# Multiline context errors

Tags: neovim, error, multiple-lines, filetype-rust

Sometimes I see multiline popup-base errors in screencasts like the one below:

[image]

Would anyone point me with a term or something to google it, as my ideas don't work for some reason?

Here's configs of the screencast author: https://github.com/jonhoo/configs/tree/master/editor/.config/nvim
I still don't know where to look there :)

Comment: I don't understand your question? It looks like this comes from a plugin, possibly ALE or ycm or coc

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I use ALE, but I've just tried COC and I still have these messages as a single line without wrapping, so almost all of them are out of screen :)

Comment: I still don't understand what you like to achieve. Please state clearly what problem you want to solve.

Comment: I want the linting message ([rustc E0608...) to be multilite as on the screenshot

Comment: I believe these are implemented with popup windows, which are a fairly recent feature of Vim. Which version of Vim or NeoVim are you running on a setup where you don't see these?

Comment: NVIM v0.4.4 - the last nvim.appimage

Comment: what is multilite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it's a pair of `COC` + `rust-analyzer`. But after playing with this I came back to `LanguageClient-neovim` + `rls`, because their single-line messages are always on screen, while multiline-once appear only if cursor is there.

Comment: Maybe could you accept your own answer. It allow the question to rest :-)